# IOS can't set FBProfilePictureView as the image view class

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I have added an imageview on my viewcontroller using storyboard and I wanted to set the class of the image view to `FBProfilePictureView` but every time I did that, xcode return the class to empty, it seems that it doesn't recognized the `FBProfilePictureView` class, though I am able to sign in and sign out and get the user's name.

I tried to make an outlet and changed the class of the imageview to `FBProfilePictureView` so the outlet becomes like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *fbImage;
```

However, when the user sign in, I am not able to show his/her picture, I got this exception:

```
2014-06-07 05:17:55.747 UITableViewControllerTutorial[1429:70b] -[UIImageView setProfileID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab52b50
```

This is my code:

```
// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    self.fbImage.profileID = user.objectID;


    self.fbName.text = user.name;
}
```

#### Note1

I already did this in `AppDelegage`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBl6GXJ9h7yYUwjA7lv48FYCzHcvEkuzIE"];
    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
    return YES;
}
```

#### Note2

I don't want to add `-ObjeC` because the official facebook tutorial states that It could raise the app's size.

#### Note3

I got that exception when I log in thought when I log in, I am able to get the user's name.

#### Note4

I am using `facebook-ios-sdk-3.14.1`

Could you help please

I appreciate your time and effots

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

I should have used UIView instead of ImageView

Regards,